# How do I left pad a byte array efficiently

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, padding

Assuming I have an array

```
LogoDataBy
{byte[0x00000008]}
    [0x00000000]: 0x41
    [0x00000001]: 0x42
    [0x00000002]: 0x43
    [0x00000003]: 0x44
    [0x00000004]: 0x31
    [0x00000005]: 0x32
    [0x00000006]: 0x33
    [0x00000007]: 0x34
```

I would like to create an array of an arbitrary length and left pad it with `0x00`

```
newArray
{byte[0x00000010]}
    [0x00000000]: 0x00
    [0x00000001]: 0x00
    [0x00000002]: 0x00
    [0x00000003]: 0x00
    [0x00000004]: 0x00
    [0x00000005]: 0x00
    [0x00000006]: 0x00
    [0x00000007]: 0x00
    [0x00000008]: 0x41
    [0x00000009]: 0x42
    [0x0000000a]: 0x43
    [0x0000000b]: 0x44
    [0x0000000c]: 0x31
    [0x0000000d]: 0x32
    [0x0000000e]: 0x33
    [0x0000000f]: 0x34
```

I have my current snippet here

```
        string test = "ABCD1234";
        byte[] LogoDataBy = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
        var newArray = new byte[16];

        var difference = newArray.Length - LogoDataBy.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < LogoDataBy.Length; i++)
        {
            newArray[difference + i] = LogoDataBy[i];
        }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: yes there is - use `Array.Copy` or `Buffer.BlockCopy` if you really need to be performant

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend starting with `Array.Copy` like this:

```
string test = "ABCD1234";
byte[] LogoDataBy = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
var newArray = new byte[16];

var startAt = newArray.Length - LogoDataBy.Length;
Array.Copy(LogoDataBy, 0, newArray, startAt, LogoDataBy.Length);
```

If you really need the speed you can do `Buffer.BlockCopy` too:

```
string test = "ABCD1234";
byte[] LogoDataBy = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(test);
var newArray = new byte[16];

var startAt = newArray.Length - LogoDataBy.Length;
Buffer.BlockCopy(LogoDataBy, 0, newArray, startAt, LogoDataBy.Length);
```

Note that I did not check the length of the array you provided - you should take care that it's *big* enough.

Comment: starting from your answer, I've written a parametric function to do this. Here the link: https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/c-left-pad-an-array/

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how you define "more efficient" then this might be worth doing:

```
var newArray =
    Enumerable
        .Repeat<Byte>(0, 16 - LogoDataBy.Length)
        .Concat(LogoDataBy)
        .ToArray();
```

This may not be computationally more efficient, but in terms of making the code clear and maintainable you might consider this am efficient way to code.

Comment: I will prefer @Carsten's answer if I'm coding networking code. I'll prefer your method if I'm coding application level program.

Comment: Why not `var newArray = new byte[16 - LogoDataBy.Length].Concat(LogoDataBy).ToArray();` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some other overloads of `GetBytes` that you can use. One of them allows you to specify a starting index in the array: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/595a8te7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You can use the `GetByteCount` method on the encoding class to get the number of bytes that will exist after the encoding, although adding this additional call may negate any performance benefit. You may know that the byte count exactly matches the string length (depending upon your string source).