# How to convert a byte array of any size to ulong in C#?

Tags: c#

Consider having various byte arrays of different lengths like:

```
byte[] a = new byte[]{0x6};
byte[] b = new byte[]{0x6, 0x33, 0x22};
byte[] c = new byte[]{0x6, 0x33, 0x22, 0x14, 0x47};
```

How to convert these byte arrays of, basically any size, except greater then 8 bytes, to `ulong`?

I'm aware of the `BitConverter` class in C#, but there you have always to provide exact number of bytes...

Comment: Presumably `new byte[] { 0x6 }` gets converted into `0x0000000000000006`?

Comment: ulong[] d = c.Select(x => (ulong)x).ToArray();

Comment: @canton7 : The code does exactly what the OP wants. The OP does not say to combine the bytes.  These are unsigned numbers and no sign extension if required.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like variable-length encoding. If you can modify the encoding end, you may want to look into using VarLong instead, which reserves the upper bit to determine if there are more bytes "left". This may end up being more useful for your usecase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily using for loops and bit shifting:

```
public static ulong BytesToUInt64(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bytes));
    if (bytes.Length > 8)
        throw new ArgumentException("Must be 8 elements or fewer", nameof(bytes));

    ulong result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        result |= (ulong)bytes[i] << (i * 8);
    }   
    
    return result;
}
```

[See it on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=).

We take the first element in the byte array, and combine it into `result` using a bitwise OR. We take the second element, shift it left 8 bits (so it sits just on top of the first element), and OR that in. And so on, for the remaining bytes.

Note that this puts the byte at index 0 in the least-significant position. You can fiddle with the indexing of `bytes` and the left shift to change this, if you need to.

---

You can also approach this by padding your byte array with 0's. Although less efficient on the face of it, it may still come out cheaper (and clearer) than the looping and bit-shifting above. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028609/how-do-i-left-pad-a-byte-array-efficiently) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can take two case into account: complete and incomplete `data` array. If you want to have `BitConverter` *improved* version:

```
public static ulong MyToUInt64(byte[] data) {
  if (null == data)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data)); // or return 0

  if (data.Length >= sizeof(ulong)) // we have enough bytes (at least 8)
    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(data, 0);

  // padded version (8 bytes) of data array
  byte[] complete = new byte[sizeof(ulong)];

  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i) 
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) // we have two ways of padding
      complete[i] = data[i];
    else 
      complete[complete.Length - i - 1] = data[data.Length - i - 1];

  return BitConverter.ToUInt64(complete);
}
```